# Sublime Text 3-Anaconda openCV docstring not working?

Tags: python, opencv, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I'm using the Anaconda plugin in Sublime Text 3. Everything was working exactly as I expected. I love Docstring. It worked great and saved me a lot of time.

But when I tried `import cv2`, cv2 was not on the autoComplete list. AutoComplete and docstring wouldn't work for anything that is in openCV.

I use Mac, with **Python 3.5.1** and **openCV 3.1.0**. In Anaconda.sublime-settings, my python interpreter is set as: `"/usr/local/bin/python3.5"` I do have another Windows with Anaconda plugin installed in ST3, and it worked fine. I don't really what is going on. Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the path where `cv2.py` and the associated `.so` files are found? How did you install the module? Does the `import cv2` command actually work? Can you use functions and so forth, even if you don't have autocomplete? Finally, how long have you waited for autocomplete to work? OpenCV is a pretty complex module, with *lots* of functions and constants.

Comment: @MattDMo I found my `cv2.so` file in python2.7 folder `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so`, not python3.5 folder. But I can't `import cv2` if I use Python 2.7. It worked only with python3.5.1.

Comment: It won't just be named `cv2.so` for Python 3, it'll be something like `cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so`. Try `import cv2; print(cv2.__file__)`. Also, do you have the answers to the rest of my questions?

Comment: @MattDMo I misunderstood :P. `cv2.__file__` returns `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so`. I can use functions without any problem, but autocomplete won't work however long I wait.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Homebrew installed (I'm a MacPorts user, when I use OS X), so I can't play around with the installation to see how well it works. However, I do have a solution that should work for you - I'm writing up the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

This setting is not documented in the default `Anaconda.sublime-settings` file, but I found it once on the [Anaconda website](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/anaconda_settings/#toc_5): `"extra_paths"`. Open your `.sublime-project` file, and add the following:

```js
{
    ...
    "settings": {
        "extra_paths":
        [
            "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/python3.5/site-package‌​s"
        ]
    }
}
```

or, if you're just using your user `Anaconda.sublime-settings`, just add:

```js
    "extra_paths":
    [
        "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/python3.5/site-package‌​s"
    ]
```

This will explicitly tell Anaconda to look there for additional modules. Hopefully that will do the trick.

Comment: I tried to add extra_paths to my user settings `Anaconda.sublime-settings` but still it didn't work. I'm so helpless :( Anyways, I'm so grateful for all your help!! Thanks so much!

Comment: @陳翰群 I may have accidentally confused you. Don't add the `{ }` curly braces to your `.sublime-settings` file. Go to the top of the file, just after the opening `{` on the first line, then, on the second line, paste the rest of what I put, with a comma `,` at the end after the last `]`, to make it valid JSON, **if** there are other settings afterwards. I hope you understand now.

Comment: I had this in my `Anaconda.sublime-settings` file:
`{
"extra_paths":
    [
        "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/python3.5/site-package‌​s"
    ],
"anaconda_tooltip_theme": "light",
...
}`
Did I do anything wrong? It still won't work..

Comment: @陳翰群 no, that's correct. You may want to browse around the issues on the project's Github site and see if that option was removed at some point.

Comment: Anaconda uses Jedi to offer auto completion, for your description looks like Jedi is not being able to analyze the opencv module for any reason. You can try to check if Jedi is working as expected in a terminal. Jusst cd to `~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/Anaconda/anaconda_lib` then write `python3.5 -c "import jedi; print(jedi.Script('import cv').completions())"`